# Yii 2 ActiveDataProvider : extra field or column of balance calculation when doing query for dataProvider

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I am trying to add new field or column of balance calculation in the ActiveDataProvider (in the transactionSearch.php model)

When I did this SQL into phpmyAdmin, it works perfectly. I got this code from stackoverflow research. Thanks

```
SET @bal = 0;
SELECT t.* , @bal:=t.amount+@bal AS balance  
FROM(
  SELECT *
  FROM transaction
  WHERE user_id = 1
) t
```

But when I am trying to fit into the transactionSearch.php model

```
$query = Transaction::find();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query
]);
```

This is what I did

```
// since I need to prepare query before starting the ActiveDataProvider query, I did this
$connectionz = Yii::$app->getDb();
$query = $connectionz->createCommand("SET @bal = 0");
$query = $query->query();
// then I run the usual query
$query = Transaction::findBySql('
                        SELECT t.* , @bal:=t.amount+@bal AS balance  
                        FROM(
                          SELECT *
                          FROM transaction
                          WHERE user_id = 1
                          ) t ')->all();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query
]);
```

Beside adding balance in **attributeLabel** & **rules**, I also added Transaction.php model the setter and getter, but I am **NOT** sure it's right or did I **lack** of adding any rules ?

```
public function setBalance($balance)
{
    $this->balance = (float) $balance;
}

public function getBalance()
{
    return '';
}
```

But it came out error `Call to a member function andFilterWhere() on array`

Any suggestions would be kindly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is

This is at the TransactionSearch.php model :

```
$expression = new Expression('@bal:=t.amount+@bal');
$connectionz = Yii::$app->getDb();
$query = $connectionz->createCommand("SET @bal = 0");
$query = $query->query();
$query = Transaction::find()
            ->from(['t' => '(
                           SELECT *
                           FROM transaction
                           WHERE user_id = 1)
                '])
            ->select(['t.*','balance' => $expression])
            ->orderBy('date');
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query
]);
```

The Transaction.php model , no need adds setter or getter, only adds:

```
public $balance;
```

In the index.php @ Transaction folder, @ gridview widget 'column' adds

```
'balance:currency:Balance',
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use SqlDataProvider

```
$connectionz = Yii::$app->getDb();
$query = $connectionz->createCommand("SET @bal = 0");
$query = $query->query();
$query = Transaction::findBySql('
                        SELECT t.* , @bal:=t.amount+@bal AS balance  
                        FROM(
                          SELECT *
                          FROM transaction
                          WHERE user_id = 1
                          ) t ');
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'query' => $query
]);
```

or

2) Add public property balance to Transaction Class. Then in sql:

```
$connectionz = Yii::$app->getDb();
$query = $connectionz->createCommand("SET @bal = 0");
$query = $query->query();
$query = Transaction::find()->where(your condition here)
->select([transaction.*,'balance'=>' @bal:=t.amount+@bal'])
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query
]);
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
$model->balance
```

Comment: Both doesn't seem to work ..........................................

1) came out error **preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given** .........................................................................................
2) came out also error **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' @bal:=t.amount+@bal' in 'field list'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `transaction`.*, ` @bal:=t`.`amount+@bal` AS `balance` FROM `transaction` WHERE `user_id`=1 ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 20**

Comment: try use http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html
->select([transaction.*,'balance'=>$expression])